# PHP - convert .wav file to .mp3?

Tags: php, audio, mp3

I was wondering if anyone had any advice for encoding a user uploaded .wav file to a .mp3 extension.  I would like to build a PHP solution if possible.  Can I call the command line LAME encoder via PHP once a file has been uploaded?  Is there a better option?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go ahead and call LAME. No chance of a better option existing, even more so if you take the encoder quality into account.

The easiest way to call into an external binary is [`exec`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), while for the best integration over the encoding process you might want to use [`proc_open`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a wrapper for LAME that provides convenient interface to encode wav file(s). The library is available here: https://github.com/b-b3rn4rd/phplame

Answer (score 0):

I do this, I downloaded and installed ffmpeg with libmp3lame.

In your code do this:

```
$commandOutput = shell_exec('ffmpeg (or path to your ffmpeg file) -i file.wav file.mp3')
```